# Добавить класс нужному элементу списка

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть список

```
<ul class="gallery-list">
      <li>
        <a href="" class="gallery-link gallery-list-active">Автомобили</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Автобусы</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Микроавтобусы</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Яхты</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Катера</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Теплоходы</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Как сделать добавление класса 'gallery-list-active' по клику и при этом нужно удалить класс у другого элемента, чтобы активный был только один.

Сделал такой код

```
var gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery-list');
var link = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-link');

for (var i=0; i<link.length; i++) {
  link[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('gallery-list-active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('gallery-list-active');
    }
    else {
      $(this).addClass('gallery-list-active');
    }
  })
}
```

Но он работает как toggle для каждого элемента списка, но не удаляет класс у других элементов.

Comment: Смешались в кучу кони, люди..... вы уж либо чистый js используйте, либо jquery. зачем этот гермафродит?)

Comment: на jquery - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/x3uqybes/

Comment: Спасибо, да, намешал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery-list');
var link = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-link');

for (var i=0; i<link.length; i++) {
  link[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    link.forEach(c => {
      c.classList.remove('gallery-list-active');
    })
      $(this).addClass('gallery-list-active');
  })
}
```

```css
.gallery-list-active {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="gallery-list">
      <li>
        <a href="" class="gallery-link gallery-list-active">Автомобили</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Автобусы</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Микроавтобусы</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Яхты</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Катера</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Теплоходы</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: чем это отличается от ответа данного раннее?

Comment: Спасибо!
Подскажите как сделать еще действия плюсом к активному классу, мне нужно поменять целый блок, чтобы когда я нажимаю на какой-нибудь элемент списка у меня менялось содержимое под этим списком, не знаю как это лучше реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Все верно, потому что вы проверяете наличи только у даного класа, а нужно у всех и у всех забирать.

```
if ($(this).hasClass('gallery-list-active')) {
  $(this).removeClass('gallery-list-active');
}
```

Вместо этого нужно снова вызвать цикл тот же и убрать класс у всех его элеметов

```js
var gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery-list');
var link = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-link');

for (var i=0; i<link.length; i++) {
  link[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    link.forEach(c => {
      c.classList.remove('gallery-list-active');
    })
      $(this).addClass('gallery-list-active');
  })
}
```

```css
.gallery-list-active {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="gallery-list">
      <li>
        <a href="" class="gallery-link gallery-list-active">Автомобили</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Автобусы</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Микроавтобусы</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Яхты</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Катера</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Теплоходы</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

```js
var gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery-list');
var link = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-link');

link.forEach(c => {
  c.addEventListener('click', () => {
    link.forEach(s => s.classList.remove('gallery-list-active'));
    c.classList.add('gallery-list-active');
  })
})
```

```css
.gallery-list-active {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="gallery-list">
      <li>
        <a href="" class="gallery-link gallery-list-active">Автомобили</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Автобусы</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Микроавтобусы</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Яхты</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Катера</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">Теплоходы</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: хых) ну уж нужно было добивать тогда  и `$(this).addClass('gallery-list-active');` на чистом js